# bash using a file name as input

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to take the output of

```
hg resolve -l
```

which is in the format

```
R somefile/filename
U somefile/filename
R somefile/filename
U somefile/filename
```

and be able to use the first line that starts with a 'U' as an argument, so I could do things like

```
open -t <first U file>
```

and

```
hg resolve -m <first U file>
```

It would be great if someone could give me some pointers about the best way to do this.

EDIT: a solution from the answers below, a simple script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script that gets the first file from hg resolve | grep U and passes to default text editor

first_u_file=$(hg resolve -l | grep -m1 '^U')
first_u_file=${first_u_file#U }
echo opening \'$first_u_file\'
open -t "$first_u_file"
```

Comment: `echo "opening '$first_u_file'"` - you don't need to escape the single quotes and the variable gets properly quoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU grep, you can try this (untested):

```
first_u_file=$(hg resolve -l | grep -m1 '^U')
first_u_file=${first_u_file#U }
```

`-mX` tells `grep` to stop after printing X lines, 1 in this case. The `$(...)` construct is similar to backticks, it turns output into a string. The second line removes "U " from the beginning of the file name.

Comment: where does this need to live? is this an alias? sorry for my minimal understanding!!

Comment: @Dori You can now use the variable, as in `open -t "$first_u_file"` and so on.

Comment: +1 great thanks! it works!! So whats going on here? If i enter the above first_u_file lines in bash it works, i tried to put them in bash_profile and it does not work. How can store this permenantly in some config file?

Comment: @Dori What exactly do you need to keep stored?

Comment: well i assume that declaring variables at the command line only persist for the terminal session? if so I would like to be able to declare them in a config file so they persist.

Comment: ah, i see my misunderstanding. i thought executing `open -t "$first_u_file"` would always grab the first file. I see that executing the variable assignment lines you first mentioned permenantly sets the value of $first_u_file var, which means i have to run those two lines every time i want to reassign. Is there not a way i can do this all in one line i.e. `open -t grab_first_file_name`?? Maybe i could do all of the above in a function?

Comment: @Dori: Functions and commands only return their exit status, not string. But you can create a script or a function that prints (echo-es) the value and then run `open -t $(grab_first_file_name)`.

Comment: You need to be careful: this solution leaves an extra blank at the beginning of first_u_file, which may be an issue depending on how it is used.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: where is the extra blank coming from?

Comment: @choroba My mistake, I thought the solution had `${first_u_file#U}` and did not notice the space after the U, which removes the space I was concerned about.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution:

```
u_file=$( hg resolve -l | awk '/^U/{print $2; exit}' )
```

Answer (score 1):

`hg resolve -l | egrep '^U.*' | head -n 1`

the output is the first U file

to use it as `open` argument with "U" dropped:

```
firstUfile=`hg resolve -l | egrep '^U.*' | head -n 1 | sed -e 's/^U\s+\(.*\)$/"\1"/'`
open -t $firstUfile
```

Comment: +1 thanks, a good start. So how do I use this as an input for `open -t`. I need to remove the 'U ' also I presume

Comment: I've edited to include U removal, I've put double quotes around the filename in case it has spaces, if you don't need it, feel free to remove from the sed substitution

Comment: this does not seem to remove the 'U ' ? Do i jut put this in .bash_proile with a preceeding `alias` ?

Comment: ah i see, its a variable, ok! executing that string of piped commands still gives me the preceeding U :(

Answer (score 1):

Rather than just open the first file, your script could iterate over all unresolved files:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read; do
    file="${REPLY#U }"
    echo "Opening '$file'"
    open -t "$file"      
    hg resolve -m "$file"
done <( hg resolve -l | grep "^U" )
```

(I'm not familiar with `hg`; would `hg resolve -aln` give you just the list of unresolved files without the "U" prefix? That would do away with the need for the grep and the U-stripping step.)